# What the different between {} and set() in python

Tags: python, list, set

recently I was reviewing my python notebook, and here comes my problem wish to share with talents here:

As far as I know, 
if you creating an **empty set** :
you can only use `set()` because `{}` will return an empty dictionary.

else: you can use both `set()`and`{}`to create a **nonempty set**.

For example:

```
a = {1,2,3,3,3,3}
a
```

it returns {1,2,3}

or 
`set(X)` something but it only takes one argument X

```
a = [1,2,3,3,3,3]
set(a)
```

it returns {1, 2, 3}.

But we cannot apply a list in `{}`

```
a = {[1,2,3,3,3,3]}
```

*TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'*

**My question is:**
1. why `{}`do not accept the list?
2. apart from creating an empty set, what are other differences between `set()` and `{}`.

If you can give some small examples to demonstrate the difference that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Because you're passing an unhashable object as a *single element* in a set, if you wanted to unpack the list to separate elements that would be `{*[...]}`

Comment: `print(type({1}))` this is a set. A dictionary is based on key-value pairs. A set is an unordered list with no duplicates.

Comment: Basically `set()` is a function that has special handling for iterator arguments. `{}` on the other hand is used for `dict` and `set` literals. A similar analogy would be to use `"1"` vs `str(1)` to create strings.